# Angular - How check if chrome extension is installed

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need an external Angular script to be able to detect if a user has my extension installed.

For example: A user installs my plugin, then goes to a website with my script on it. The website detects that my extension is installed and updates the page accordingly.

My code:

```
$.detectChromeExtension('[[id_chrome_extension]]', 'images/logo.png', myCallbackFunction);

$.detectChromeExtension = function(extensionId, accesibleResource, callback) {
    if (typeof(chrome) !== 'undefined'){
        var testUrl = 'chrome-extension://' +extensionId +'/' +accesibleResource;
        console.log(testUrl);
        $.ajax({
            url: testUrl,
            timeout: 1000,
            type: 'HEAD',
            success: function(){
                if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
                    callback.call(this, true);
                }
            },
            error: function() {                
                if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
                    callback.call(this, false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
            callback.call(this, false);
        }
    }
};
```

I receive the following error:

> `HEAD chrome-extension://[[id_chrome_extension]]/images/logo.png net::ERR_FAILED jquery.js:86235`
>   `Uncaught Error: A Chrome Web Store installation is already pending.`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Just to make sure, the `[[id_chrome_extension]]` is a placeholder for an actual ID in your code?

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) api, which also works for apps.

Add this to your manifest:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

Then send a message to your extension from the page:

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

And listen for messages in your extension:

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```

---

Comment: does the chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal should be in Content.js or background.js ??