# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined when detecting chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have written a chrome extension, which is called from an external web page (which is deployed in a local server tomcat) via native messaging. we want the external page to first detect that the chrome extension is installed by the user and then communicate with the extension. 
this is the extension manifest file:

```
"permissions":
[
"tabs",
"http://*/*",
"nativeMessaging",
"management"
],
"externally_connectable":
{
"matches": ["http://localhost:8080/test.jsp"]}

]
```

the external page calls the extension as:

```
chrome.management.get(extension_id,function(a){alert("hi");});
```

but I got an error in chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

can anyone help to solve the problem in order to detect the installed extension.

Thanks.

Comment: Dear @ wOxxOm I am using it in an external web page which is deployed in a local web server.

Comment: As you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) the only available API are `chrome.runtime.connect` and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

Comment: Dear @ wOxxOm, you mean there is no way to detect from external web page that a specific extension is installed?

Comment: Yes, I googled but they all use chrome.management.get, but I get an error when calling this.

Comment: Not true. See [Angular - How check if chrome extension is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25734472)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve the wrong problem.

If your extension is `externally_connectable`, you should *just try to connect*. You'll get a meaningful error otherwise.

Do note that `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` will ONLY be exposed to the page if at least one `externally_connectable` extension is ready to listen. So you need to check that as well:

```
if(chrome && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.sendMessage) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    extension_id,
    message,
    onMessageCallback
  );
}

function onMessageCallback(response) {
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    // Something went wrong, probably the right extension is not installed
  }
}
```

Just make sure there actually *is* code listening to `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` in your extension.